# Is this the correct method to find $d^2 y/d x^2$ in terms of $y_t,x_t,x_{tt},y_{tt}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose $y$ and $x$ are functions of $t$. Then I have $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}$$

After that is it correct to apply $\dfrac{u}{v}$ rule to find $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ like $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}\right)=\dfrac{\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\left(\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}\right)\left(\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)\left(\dfrac{dt}{dx}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{dx}{dt}\right)^2}$$ (using $(dx/dt)(dt/dx)=1$) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, since $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{d} / \mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x/ \mathrm{d} t},$$ so
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y / \mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x/ \mathrm{d} t} \right) = \displaystyle \frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y / \mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x/ \mathrm{d} t}\right)}{\mathrm{d}x/ \mathrm{d} t} = \displaystyle \frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y/\mathrm{d}t^2 \cdot \mathrm{d}x/ \mathrm{d} t - \mathrm{d}^2x/\mathrm{d}t^2 \cdot \mathrm{d}y/ \mathrm{d} t}{(\mathrm{d}x/ \mathrm{d} t)^2} }{\mathrm{d}x/ \mathrm{d} t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2y/\mathrm{d}t^2 \cdot \mathrm{d}x/ \mathrm{d} t - \mathrm{d}^2x/\mathrm{d}t^2 \cdot \mathrm{d}y/ \mathrm{d} t}{(\mathrm{d}x/ \mathrm{d} t)^3}
$$
This stuck with me due to the unusual looking cubed term on the denominator.

As you say, dividing by $\mathrm{d}x/ \mathrm{d} t$ and using the chain rule would give your result.